# Type Casting for uitextfield in montouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I need to create the UITextField as a name of string that i'm getting from Service.
I tried the following way

```
string name = "Sample";
UITextField name = new UITextField();
```

But i'm getting already defined data Type error.

Please give me the solution.

Thank you in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two variables named the same. This is a general C# syntax issue.

Does it work if you do this:

```
string name = "Sample";
UITextField nameField = new UITextField();
```

Comment: ya 
string name = "Sample";
UITextField nameField = new UITextField(); 
it will work

Comment: If that solved your problem, generally people upvote answers or mark them as solved. Just noticed you seem new to stackoverflow.